# Chase Bank/Credit Card & Internet Explorer 8 / 9 and Chrome Cookies for logging in

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, cookies

I frequently clear out my cookies, whenever I do this and then go to my credit card for Chase they require I get an email or text or phone call with a special code (quite a pain).  Is there a way to set that the cookies for just Chase website DO NOT get erased when I delete all browsing/cookie history?

Currently using Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112.16421) but my primary is Chrome (21.0.1180.60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) - it 'intelligently' scans your cookies and decides which to remove or keep? Sadly, you have to try to see for sure though!

Comment: I havent tried CCleaner might be an option, I currently have chrome with History Eraser and have not yet checked to see if there is option for selecting particular cookies.  - Otherwise I think this is possibly a good route to look into, even if it doesnt work it is certainly good way of thinking outside the box.